# Can I use SSD on new PC build?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I'm new to PC Building world, so I just want to make sure of something before I mess things up.

I'm building a new PC and I have Samsung 850 EVO SSD, **my question is when I power on the PC for the first time and Install Windows 10 using Bootable USB Flash drive, will the SSD be shown as available storage to install Windows 10 on it ?** or there is kind of configuration for the SSD before use ? and if there will be a problem does using HDD will solve the problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, as this is not as obvious as most people think.

There are 2 possibilities:

1. If the SSD has a SATA connector, like a regular HDD, it is interchangeable with a regular HDD. (Most EVO 850 models fall in this category, but not all.)

   In that case no special settings in the computers BIOS are required and the Windows installation (regardless which Windows version) should also see it as a normal drive. (Provided of course that Windows has a standard drivers for the SATA controller chip in your motherboard, but that is almost guaranteed with Windows 10.)
2. When the SSD comes in the form of a small printed circuit board to fit in a special SSD slot on the motherboard it gets more complicated.
   Several different type of slots exist (M-SATA, M2, M2-Nvme) and the slot and the SSD must be of compatible types.

   To complicate matters even more: Even if the type matches also the form-factor must fit. These small form-factor SSDs come in several physical sizes and not all with fit in the space provided by the motherboard. (Some are too long or have the hole for the retaining screw in the wrong place.)

   In case of such a SSD it is often required to enable the slot in the BIOS settings first. In some BIOSses you must also explicitly configure it as a boot device (otherwise the system keeps trying to boot from the normal SATA).

   Last, but not least: Depending on the exact motherboard it may be necessary (should be documented in the motherboard manual) to manually load the required drivers during the Windows setup, before the setup will be able to detect the SSD. After the setup has seen the SSD it is treated as a normal HDD drive.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, Yes SSD has a SATA Connector, and the Motherboard is Ready for Win10, but I'll take a look in Motherboard manual to see if there is anything needed for installing windows.

Comment: You can always get an adapter bracket if your SSD won't fit anywhere in your case.  They are cheap, and allow you to mount a 2.5inch SSD in a 3.5inch bay/slot.

Comment: @TimmyJim thanks, my case comes with several brackets.